# Proof verification: approximate identity for function $f(x)= (1-|x|) \chi_{[-1,1]}(x) $

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis, solution-verification, lebesgue-integral

I want to construct an approximate identity for the function $f(x)= (1-|x|) \chi_{[-1,1]}(x)  $ in following way:

$\phi _t (x) = \frac{1}{t} f(\frac{x}{t}) = \frac{1}{t} (1- \frac{|x|}{t}) \chi_{[-t,t]}(x) $ ,  when
$t\rightarrow 0$ from right.

I verified that  $\phi _t (x) \geq 0$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}  \phi _t (x) dx =1$ and I tried to prove the third property i.e. $\int_{|x| \geq \delta}  \phi _t (x) dx  \rightarrow 0$ when $t  \rightarrow 0$, for every $\delta > 0$. Can someone just check if this is correct:

We take arbitrary $\delta > 0$. Since  $t  \rightarrow 0$, we can find $t_0 < \delta $ such that for all $t \leq t_0$ holds:  $\chi_{[-t,t]}(x) =0$. Then it follows that $(1-\frac{|x|}{t}) \chi_{[-t,t]}(x) \rightarrow 0 $ when $t  \rightarrow 0$. This function is dominated by a integrable function and according to Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem, it follows that $\int_{|x| \geq \delta}  \phi _t (x) dx  \rightarrow 0$ when $t  \rightarrow 0$, for every $\delta > 0$.

Could someone please check this solution? I can't find any similar solved tasks on this topic, so I would also be very thankful if someone recommends a book or link. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to use dominated convergence theorem.

Fix $\delta > 0$. Suppose that $|t| < \delta$ and  $|x| \ge \delta$. Hence $\chi_{[-t,t]}(x) = 0$ and it follows that $\int_{|x| \ge \delta} \phi_t(x)dx = 0$.